# Is there an Android equivalent to ActionListener?

Tags: java, android, actionlistener

What I essentially need is an action listener that notes if another touchable views have been clicked so that they can be set to enabled (i.e., if imageview1 is clicked, imageview2 can now be clicked whereas before it could not). I was looking around and found `ActionListener` and ActionEvents, but after importing all necessary packages, updating my SDK, and syncing my gradle files, Android Studio still doesn't recognize those options. I can't seem to find a way to get it to work. Is there something I'm missing in getting them to resolve, or is there another kind of listener I can use?

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/sq2"
        android:background="@color/preFocus"
        android:onClick="imagePress"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/sq3"
        android:nextFocusUp="@+id/sq1"
        android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/sq4"
        android:nextFocusRight="@id/sq4"
         />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
        android:background="@color/preFocus"
        android:id="@id/sq4"
        android:onClick="imagePress"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:nextFocusDown="@id/sq3"
        android:nextFocusUp="@id/sq1"
        android:nextFocusLeft="@id/sq2"
        android:nextFocusRight="@id/sq2"
        />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="400dp"
        android:background="@color/preFocus"
        android:id="@id/sq3"
        android:onClick="imagePress"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:nextFocusDown="@id/sq1"
        android:nextFocusUp="@id/sq1"
        android:nextFocusLeft="@id/sq2"
        android:nextFocusRight="@id/sq4"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="@color/preFocus"
        android:id="@id/sq1"
        android:onClick="imagePress"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:nextFocusDown="@id/sq3"
        android:nextFocusUp="@id/sq3"
        android:nextFocusLeft="@id/sq2"
        android:nextFocusRight="@id/sq4">
            <requestFocus />
    </ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java:

```
package com.example.mcken.spinnertest;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.media.Image;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder;
import android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;




import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        final int childcount = rl.getChildCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < childcount; i++){
            final View square = rl.getChildAt(i);
            final View nextSquare = rl.getChildAt(i+1);
            square.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent click){
                    nextSquare.setEnabled(true);
                }
            });
        }

    }

    public void clickableChange(){
        //what am I trying to do
        //set an actionlistener
        //if this is clicked
        //the "next" one is clickable

//        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
//        final int childcount = rl.getChildCount();
//
//        for (int i = 0; i < childcount; i++){
//            final View square = rl.getChildAt(i);
//            final View nextSquare = rl.getChildAt(i+1);
//            square.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
//                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent click){
//                    nextSquare.setEnabled(true);
//                }
//            });
//        }
    }

    public void imagePress(View test){
        int id = test.getId();
        ImageView picture = (ImageView) findViewById(id);

        final int pictureId = id;
        picture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, view);
                popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu,popup.getMenu());


                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener(){
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem selection){
                        ImageView thisThing = (ImageView) findViewById(pictureId);
                        Drawable icon = selection.getIcon();

                        thisThing.setImageDrawable(icon);
                        return true;
                    }
                });

                popup.show();


            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need for Action Listener .  Initally set  the button2 disabled by setting android:enabled=false . Then use setOnClickListener on button1 and its onClick method  set [button2].setEnabled(true);

Comment: Is there a way to set the onClick for whatever the next view is setEnabled()=true? I have 10 views I'll need to manage in this fashion; i.e. they can only be clicked if the one before is clicked.  Maybe have two id's in the imagePress() method, and when that ID is clicked, the one after is set to enabled? But then how would I wrap it back to the first if someone clicks the last ImageView?

Comment: You can try using `RadioGroup` along with `RadioButtons`. You can make it look like a button by removing the button from it.